# Why does InnoDB keep failing with auto autoextend?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

After moving servers MariaDB keeps failing to start.

I had to copy over the /var/lib/mysql folder as disks had failed and i was not able to chroot in the os.

after copying over the folder MariaDB failed to start.

the error i am getting:

```
022-07-29 16:22:22 0 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: option '--innodb-data-file-path' requires an argument
2022-07-29 16:22:22 0 [ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed.
2022-07-29 16:22:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 16:22:22 0 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--innodb_data_file_path'
2022-07-29 16:22:22 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-07-29 16:22:25 0 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: option '--innodb-data-file-path' requires an argument
2022-07-29 16:22:25 0 [ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed.
2022-07-29 16:22:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 16:22:25 0 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--innodb_data_file_path'
2022-07-29 16:22:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-07-29 16:27:45 0 [Warning] mysqld: GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/my-seeyou-go@' not found in keytab
2022-07-29 16:27:45 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty.
2022-07-29 16:27:45 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.32 started; log sequence number 1625443; transaction id 20
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220729 16:27:47
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Warning] mysqld: GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/my-seeyou-go@' not found in keytab
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2022-07-29 16:27:47 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.32-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql_org_10.3/ib_buffer_pool
2022-07-29 16:30:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220729 16:30:46
2022-07-29 16:30:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-07-29 16:30:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625452; transaction id 21
2022-07-29 16:30:47 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: This question is better suited to the site dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I did not spot anything obviously wrong.  However 10.3.2 sounds like a pre-release version number.  Suggest you upgrade to at least of newer 10.3.x.